# How to rotate a TShape

Tags: delphi

I have a TShape on my form.  and would like to rotate it. Can this be done with TShape? If so How?  I assume its just drawing the shape according to some coords. Maybe there is Coords that can be changed? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately this can't be done. You could write your own components based on TShape that supports this though.

Comment: Bad shape, maybe in next version of Delphi they will upgrade shapes "D

Comment: I succeded to rotate and even scale a tShape. First, you declare a class derived from tShape (tMyShape = class (tShape). In this class, you publish the Rotate and Scale properies from tControl ancestor and that's it! Now when you modify those properties, the tShape is rotated and scaled properly. Hope this help.